# I am not able to apply color picker js(jscolor.js) on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code html code

```
   <head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jscolor-2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
      <body>

        <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var max_fields      = 10; 
       var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
          var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 

       var x = 1; 
         $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault();
          if(x < max_fields){ 
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append('<div>Case :<input type="text" name="mytext"> Color Picker :  <input class="jscolor" name="c_picker"><br><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
  });
  </script>


        <form>
    DB-URl  :
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br/>
      Username:
    <input type="text" name="lastname"><br/>
    Password:
   <input type="password" name="Password"><br>
    Table Name:
    <input type="text" name="t_name"><br>
    Color column:
   <input type="text" name="c_column"><br>
  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div>Case :<input type="text" name="mytext">  Color Picker :  <input  class="jscolor" name="c_picker"><br></div>
      </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Update" id="updating">  
 </form>
```

First Time color picker js is apply on input field   but when I add more color picker field dynamically color picker js is not apply on next input field. Can anybody explain me why this is happening?

Comment: `First Time color picker js is apply on input field` show this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jscolor()` to `bind` the newly appended element:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                var max_fields = 10;
                var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
                var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

                var x = 1;
                $(add_button).click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (x < max_fields) {
                        x++;
                        $(wrapper).append('<div>Case :<input type="text" name="mytext">Color Picker : <input class="jscolor" name="c_picker"><br><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
                        var color = new jscolor($(wrapper).find('input.jscolor:last')[0]);
                        //$(wrapper).find('input.jscolor:last').each(function () {
                            //var color = new jscolor($(this)[0]);

                    //});


                    }
                });

                $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
                });
            });
```

Comment: No need to loop through all the inputs (it's not an efficient way) you could see the **Warning** `Cannot link jscolor twice to the same element. Skipping.` in the console every time you're trying to init the input that are already initialized...

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Now the warning is removed :) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could init the jsColor on the added input using :

```
new jscolor($('.jscolor').last()[0]);
```

**NOTE :** No need to loop through all the inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add_field_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('form').append('<div>Case :<input type="text" name="mytext">        Color Picker :  <input class="jscolor" name="c_picker"><br><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');

    new jscolor($('.jscolor').last()[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <br><br>
    <div>Case :<input type="text" name="mytext">  Color Picker :  <input  class="jscolor" name="c_picker"><br></div>
  </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: one more help....what to do if i want to retun value in input field as RGB not Hexa color code...here it returns hexa color code

Comment: Take a look to `Getting colors` in http://jscolor.com/examples/ or also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8868430/4281779

Answer (score 2):

This is solved at this stackoverflow question:
[using jscolor.js on dynamic input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693118/using-jscolor-js-on-dynamic-input)

The solution was to add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the date picker is created when the document is loaded.

If you insert a new HTML element after the doc is loaded, you will need to assign a unique ID to each new element and attach the color picker manually using this code:

```
$("#idOfNewElement").colorpicker();
```