# How to reinitialize a script in an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscolor

I have a document that uses the [jscolor.com](http://jscolor.com) library, for the user to be able to select and store a color. I'm also using a JQuery function to add rows to the screen, so the user can create and define a number of colors. The problem is, when the new row is added, the Javascript isn't re-initialized for the added elements.

Here is the code in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<div id='addr" + i + "'>" +
            "<div class='col-xs-4'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='config_color[" + i + "][css]' id='input-color[" + i + "][css]' class='form-control' />" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='col-xs-2'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='config_color[" + i + "][value]' id='input-color[" + i + "][value]' class='form-control jscolor' />" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='col-xs-2'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='config_color[" + i + "][default]' id='input-color[" + i + "][default]' class='form-control' />" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='col-xs-4'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='config_color[" + i + "][notes]' id='input-color[" + i + "][notes]' class='form-control' />" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<div id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></div>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i>1){
            $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
}).trigger('change');
</script>
```

I've made an simplified example of what I'm talking about on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71crdj4r/) - you can see in the first row, if you click in the color cell, it gives you a pop up color palette.

If you add additional rows, the popup picker doesn't work.

However, all of the data stores in the database properly, so i have an instance where some elements added by Javascript work properly and others don't?

(Also full disclosure, I asked on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/jquery/comments/631pkp/javascript_not_firing_from_dynamically_added/) first - this is therefore a cross-post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their [examples](http://jscolor.com/examples/), jscolor has one called "Instantiating new Color Pickers" which shows you how to do it.

You're adding the new row as a string, which I wouldn't recommend, because if you [created each input separately using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619445/the-prefered-way-of-creating-a-new-element-with-jquery) it would be easier to call `jscolor()` on only one element, but this works too.

Just add the following to your click handler:

```
// Get all the inputs first
var allInputs = $('.jscolor');

// From there, get the newest one
var newestInput = allInputs[allInputs.length - 1]; 

// And call jscolor() on it!
new jscolor(newestInput);
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71crdj4r/1/)

Comment: You don't have to query all pickers. I've modified your [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/71crdj4r/2/)

Comment: I didn't reinstantiate all pickers, I only get the newest picker with `allInputs.length - 1`. Yours, however, is more succinct. I didn't think to use the index in the name/ID in the selector

Answer (score 0):

Generally *Abe Fehr* answer helped me too, but i had slightly other problem. My elements already had default values from database so

```
new jscolor(newestInput);
```

initialized them but with default *FFFFF*

So in my case twig (html) looks like this:

```
<button class="jscolor {value:'{{ category.color }}'} btn btn-sm disabled color-picker" data-color="{{ category.color }}"></button>
```

And then I reinitialize all the colors like this:

```
    let all_pickers = $('.color-picker');

    if ($(all_pickers).length !== 0) {

        $(all_pickers).each((index, element) => {
            let color = $(element).attr('data-color');
            new jscolor(element, {'value': color});
        });

    }
```