# Why JSColor is not initializing on input?

Tags: javascript, jscolor

I'm trying to integrate `jscolor` in a page but it's not working

**Input:**

```
<input type="text" id="background_color" name="background_color" class="jscolor" placeholder="Background Color" data-bind="value: background_color">
```

**JSColor CDN Link:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-js/1.0.1/color.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not getting any errors in console! When I click the input field it doesn't show the color picker!

**Snippet:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-js/1.0.1/color.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="background_color" name="background_color" class="jscolor" placeholder="Background Color" data-bind="value: background_color">
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem was in the `src` url I was using for js-color library. From the answer below I got the correct URL!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using jscolor.js on dynamic input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693118/using-jscolor-js-on-dynamic-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found a different URL that makes it work:

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"
```

I assume this is fine, unless you really want to specifically use that version/library, though I'm not sure if your URL is JSColor or some different library.